# Фон для EditText

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. У меня есть `EditText`, который я создаю динамически. Возможно ли в `java` коде применить к нему фон? Не просто цвет, а фон-разметка. Или хотя бы просто сделать обводку. В `xml` это происходит так: "`android:background="@drawable/...`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Пример программного создания кнопки](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/50-urok-17-sozdanie-view-komponent-v-rabochem-prilozhenii.html).
По идее все то же самое по аналогии но имхо геморрно и громоздко,  может лучше использовать `LayoutInflater` ?